# Consuming Asp.net web service from remote computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, networking, iis-7.5

I create Asp.net WS and host it on the IIS.Now i want to consume it from remote computer or another computer.When i insert the URL of the WS on the remote computer an error message appears inside internet explorer browser page says

```
This program cannot display the web page
```

i work on Visual studio 2008, windows 7 and the client application is Asp.net website.
i don't know what is the problem??
have i connect the two computers with LAN(make network between them) or just enough each one connect to the internet??

Answer (score 0):

Your computers need to be able to connect to each other.
If they on LAN, then You need to specify LAN address for asp.net WS.

Also check Your firewall for blocking connections, need to be sure that port were IIS hosted is available for connection

If nothing helps, then provide us more information about problem.

Comment: If i want to host my WS on the internet.Is there any websites to host my WS.And in this case how can i access(consume) the WS??

Comment: In general You need a hosting for such things. But You can try AppHarbor, it has 1 free application in plan

Comment: I connect the two devices via LAN cable without make any configurations on the windows.Still the same error appears.Can any one helps me in what i should do in windows firewall to show the page?? Or what is the problem??

Comment: Can you ping your server from your client machine?

Comment: Sorry ASetty i can't understand what you write??

Answer (score 0):

Really i don't know what is the problem.When i do the same thing in **another computer** it runs but on my laptop doesn't run.